# Do until loop won't exit

Tags: c#

This must be a silly question but with my logic i can't understand why it doesn't exit.
This is my loop:

```
Random _random = new Random();
int num;
char let;
string TempName = "~";
string sTempPath;
do
{
    while (TempName.Length < 12)
    {
        num = _random.Next(0, 26);
        let = (char)('a' + num);
        TempName = TempName + let;
    }
    sTempPath = sDirectory + @"\" + TempName + @"." + sExt;
    //MessageBox.Show(sTempPath);
} while (!File.Exists(sTempPath));
```

So with my logic, when Do loop starts, it directly triggers the while loop Inside it. While loop exists after `TempName.Length` is greater than 12 and then do loop should exit since the file doesn't exists.
So where am i wrong?

Comment: It seems to me it would be *very* easy to figure this out with a short session in the debugger.

Comment: That TempName variable looks like it would need to be reset before you enter the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your loop runs *as long as* `File` doesn't exist. If you wanna stop when the file doesn't exist then change your condition to `File.Exists` by removing negation operator (!).

Comment: For God's sake, i am sure it was something simple i was missing. I feel so dump...

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is incorrect.

`while(File.Exists(sTempPath))`

Answer (score 0):

```
Random _random = new Random();
int num;
char let;
string TempName = "~";
string sTempPath = string.Empty;
while (TempName.Length < 12 || File.Exists(sTempPath))
{
    num = _random.Next(0, 26);
    let = (char)('a' + num);
    TempName = TempName + let;
    sTempPath = sDirectory + @"\" + TempName + @"." + sExt;
}
```